# Unable to create an object and use its methods of template class

Tags: c++

I am pretty much new to use of templates in C++.
Following is the code which I am trying to use. I am unable to use the following the code, as I cannot figure out as how to create the object for it and use the method defined in it.

```
 template <typename UInt> class nCr {
  public:
      typedef UInt result_type;
      typedef UInt first_argument_type;
      typedef UInt second_argument_type;

      result_type operator()(first_argument_type n, second_argument_type k) {
          if (n_ != n) {
              n_ = n;
              B_.resize(n);
          } // if n

          return B_[k];
      } // operator()

  private:
      int n_ = -1;
      std::vector<result_type> B_;

  };
```

And how I am creating the object is :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "math.hpp" // WHere the above class nCr is defined

int main() {
    int n =4;
    nCr x(4,2);

    return 0;
}
```

For this I am creating the error as

```
error: use of class template 'jaz::Binom' requires template arguments      
        nCr x(4,2);        
             ^
./include/math.hpp:68:34: note: template is declared here      
  template <typename UInt> class nCr {       
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~       ^
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 1st error, `nCr` is a template class, you need to specify the template argument when you mention it, such as `nCr<int>`.

The 2nd error, `nCr<int> x(4,2);` means construct a `nCr<int>` via its constructor which takes two parameters, but `nCr` doesn't have such constructor. Instead, you're defining `operator()` in `nCr`, so you might mean

```
nCr<int> x;
int result = x(4, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a template class, specify the argument:

```
nCr<int> x;
```

Since there's no matching constructor, `nCr<int> x(4,2) // doesn't work`

First declare `x`, and call the `operator()` that you defined in the class:

```
nCr<int> x;
int value = x(4,2);
```